# Finding the largest element in an Array

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, element

I'm trying to write a **for** loop that finds the largest element in the **array** and log that element to the console. I got this so far but it doesn't work. Can anyone help?

```
var array = [3, 6, 2, 56, 32, 5, 89, 32];
var largest = 0;

for (var i = 0; 0 < 100; i++ ) {
    if (array[i] > largest) {
       largest = array[i]);
    }
}

console.log(largest);
```

Comment: `Math.max.apply(0,array) // 89`

Comment: Or Math.max(0,150,30,20,38); <- no apply or loop needed if you can put them as arguments.

Comment: [Learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners).

Comment: There are also syntax errors, remove `(` from `(if`, and `)` from `array[i]);`

Answer (score 0):

Change the for-loop to:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
```

@plalx is right, there's one more issue, in the line:

```
largest = array[i]);
```

There's an unnecessary closing bracket ")" which should be removed.
Apply these two changes - and the code will work.

Comment: It's not the only issue =P

Comment: @plalx you're right - there was one more issue, see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, @elclanrs said it in comments already, however...

You can use [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max), which takes a various number of numbers as arguments. However `Math.max` doesn't take an array as argument, so we use [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to pass every element in the array as individual arguments.

`Math.max.apply(Math, [3, 6, 2, 56, 32, 5, 89, 32]);`

*Note: The first argument of apply is the object to which the context object will be set when executing the function. In other words, it specifies the value of `this`. In this case it could be `null` and it wouldn't make any difference.*

As for your initial code, you have some syntax errors and you should [**lint**](http://www.jshint.com/) your code.

Answer (score 0):

like @elclanrs said, you want to use the built-in `Math.max` function. You could simply write:

```
var array = [3, 6, 2, 56, 32, 5, 89, 32];
var largest = Math.max.apply(null, array);
```

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max